# Linux - give specific users and groups different permissions for 1 folder

Tags: linux, permissions

I know the question seems to be duplicated, but I can't find any answer out there so I would like to ask for your help. Detailed commands are greatly appreciated.

I am the owner of the folder called MyFolder and I need to grant the permission for the groups below to access it.

- Users belonging to group G1 can read, write, execute
- Users belonging to group G2 can read only
- Users who are not in group G1, G2 will not be able to do anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should study the docs on ACL which gives flexibility to the standard user/group permission system making it look like that of windows.
An example of the many writings: http://thegeekdiary.com/unix-linux-access-control-lists-acls-basics/